# How to programmatically set the background on a UICustomButton?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uibutton, uiimage

I know this question has been asked and answered in other forums, but I can't seem to duplicate what they did and get it to work. I am trying to set the background to a button using a picture that I download from a server. Everything works until I try to make a NSData object with the contents of a URL. When I try and print the Data to the screen it comes back Null. What am I doing wrong?

```
myImageURLString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://destinationnexus.com"];
    keyName = [businessButtonTagArray objectAtIndex:i];
    arrayFromBusinessDictionary = [businessDictionary objectForKey:keyName];
    stringToAddToMyImageURLString = [arrayFromBusinessDictionary objectAtIndex:1];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTag:i];  
    button.frame = CGRectMake(xOffSet+(countForX*xMult), yOffset +(countForY*yMult), 215, 155);

    [myImageURLString appendString:stringToAddToMyImageURLString];
    NSLog(@"Appended URL String: = %@", myImageURLString);


    NSURL *myImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://destinationnexus.com/pictures/directory/ColdWater-Inn-in-Tuscumbia-Alabama-35674-8729//.jpg"];
    NSLog(@"NSURL = %@", myImageURL);
    //THIS IS WHERE I SEEM TO HAVE A PROBLEM.....
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myImageURL];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData] ;
    NSLog(@"Image Data = %@", imageData);
    //UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData] ; 
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

When I run the program this is what it outputs in the Log:

Appended URL String: = http://destinationnexus.com/pictures/directory/Auburn-University-Hotel-and-Center-in-Auburn-Alabama-36830-5429.jpg

NSURL = http://destinationnexus.com/pictures/directory/ColdWater-Inn-in-Tuscumbia-Alabama-35674-8729.jpg

Image Data = (null)

Comment: NSLog(@"NSURL = %@", myImageURL);
what's the output?

Comment: @URLArenzo it changes because it is dynamically setting backgrounds to a number of different buttons, but an example would be:NSURL = http://destinationnexus.com/pictures/directory/Columbus-Street-Inn-in-Fayette-Alabama-35555.jpg

Comment: Oh, have you ever tried to download the image from the NSURL above?
Check the URL.

Comment: Ya if you take the address and pull it up in a browser, it will get the picture. I don't think that that is the problem...I'll try a couple of different images though to see if maybe it is the server

Comment: Try yourself. Copy NSURL address in browser and you will see, that there is no image.

Comment: Ya you were right there was something wrong with it in the code I posted sorry, but I corrected it on the post as well as double checked the program. I had just copied it over wrong from the output. The URL's from the output work perfectly but the application still isn't working

Comment: In your code, you've got 2 slashes that you don't have in your log.  They appear right before the .jpg in the URL string.  (//.jpg)

Comment: http://destinationnexus.com/pictures/directory/ColdWater-Inn-in-Tuscumbia-Alabama-35674-8729.jpg is the actual output

Comment: Not understanding the code then.  You're setting myimageURLString and then never using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should correct your myImageURL, by deleting 2 slashes at the end of URL.

The code goes something like this.

```
NSURL *myImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://destinationnexus.com/pictures/directory/ColdWater-Inn-in-Tuscumbia-Alabama-35674-8729.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myImageURL];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData] ;
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[image release];
[imageData release];
```